# A problem related to inclusion-exclusion principle

Tags: combinatorics

Given N positive integers, not necessarily distinct, how many ways you can take 4 integers from the N numbers such that their GCD is 1.
For example,N=10 and the positive integers are 12,46,100,131,5,6,7,8,9 and 10,
the result will be 195.

How can I find out the number of ways using inclusion-exclusion principle? I'm a novice in learning inclusion-exclusion principle.So I need better explanation.